# Variable cannot be accessed below a certain point in the code

Tags: c#

I have a small problem with a piece of code I cannot seem to work out what the issue is, I never wrote this initial part of the code which is why I don't understand the problem.

**Code:**

```
        public async Task GetEnumerableLinksAsync(string entryPointUrl)
        {
            Uri baseUrl = new Uri(entryPointUrl);
            await foreach (Uri url in GetEnumerableLinksAsync(baseUrl, 1000))
                ListBoxMain.Items.Add(url);
                // TEST
                string[] threads = File.ReadAllLines(@"logic\markers.txt");
                if (threads.Any(url.Contains)) { 
            
                }
                // TEST
        }
```

The problem is here `if (threads.Any(url.Contains)) {`  I cannot access the `url` variable.

`ListBoxMain.Items.Add(url);` the listbox can access it fine, but any code below this and I get `` the name `url` does not exist in the current context ``

Can anyone see the issue at all? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding braces to your `foreach` and you will see the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written looks correct because of indentation, but C# ignores any formatting.

This is your code formatted properly:

```
await foreach (Uri url in GetEnumerableLinksAsync(baseUrl, 1000))
    ListBoxMain.Items.Add(url);
// TEST
string[] threads = File.ReadAllLines(@"logic\markers.txt");
if (threads.Any(url.Contains)) { 
        
}
// TEST
```

Can you see the why url doesn't exist after the `foreach` now?

You need to add a 'scope' to the foreach to allow `url` to exist beyond the first line:

```
await foreach (Uri url in GetEnumerableLinksAsync(baseUrl, 1000))
{
    ListBoxMain.Items.Add(url);
    // TEST
    string[] threads = File.ReadAllLines(@"logic\markers.txt");
    if (threads.Any(url.Contains)) { 
        
    }
    // TEST
}
```

Two hints:

- start using Ctrl+KD more often.  This formats your code and would have shown the issue.
- Always use braces when using compound functions, like if,else,foreach etc.

Comment: Thank you Neil I see the issue now, i always like to use brackets, i knew the code looked kind of right but wrong lol thank you again.